# Why wont the $id variable display?

Tags: php, xml

For some reason, this variable wont display. Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once("functions/redirect.php");
require_once("functions/connect.php");
require_once("queries/member-table-query.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];

// Query the db to get all of the info to put in the XML file
$result  =  mysql_query("SELECT members.* FROM members JOIN $nombre ON     members.member_ID=$nombre.friends") or die(mysql_error());
 $number  =  mysql_num_rows($result);


$xmlout  =  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><Peers>";
while($msg = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $xmlout .= "<friend lang='en'>
     <name>".$msg['first_name']." ".$msg['last_name']."</name>
     <url>petition_invite_member.php?petition_ID=$id&  amp;member_ID=".$msg['member_ID']."  </url>
     <photo>".$msg['photo']."</photo>
     <location>".$msg['home_state']." - ".$msg['district']."</location>
    </friend>";
}
$xmlout .= "</Peers>";
?>
```

For some reason, the $id variable doesn't display between the  tags in the url.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what does `var_dump($id);` right after `$id=$_GET["id"];` return?

Comment: the value of $id is dynamic. it's an integer that can be up to 1-15 digits long

Comment: I this you are fetching wrong key from query string. you should use $id = $_GET["petition_ID"];

Comment: Is `$id` really not empty? Does it show something when you do an `echo $id;` ?

Comment: $id is def not empty. in the case i'm workining with now, it's equal to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the value of the $id in the URL tags, I don't see it.

Comment: <url>petition_invite_member.php?petition_ID=$id&  amp;member_ID=".$msg['member_ID']."  </url>

Answer (score 0):

the & immediatly after the $id is probably confusing php. Try

```
${id}&amp;
```

instead.

Comment: that still doesn't work. i really think that this one may have stumped me :(

Answer (score 0):

can you try to put in this way?

petition_invite_member.php?petition_ID=".$id."&member_ID=".$msg['member_ID']."

Add the double quote before and after $id as you did in $msg.
Thanks

Comment: tried it... still doesn't work! this code has been confusing me for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

exactly

```
petition_ID={$id}&amp;
```

also you may be sure that $id variable doesn't empty